# Secondary display option is gone in settings -> display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop named ASUS Zenbook Pro Duo UX571LV.

The first time I've installed Ubuntu 20.04, the display settings had options to set up the secondary display.

But after a long while of installing tweaks and updates and extended use, My secondary display is completely black, and my performance somehow plummeted. I did try to use back up to an earlier point, but my pc remained the same.

Do you guys have any solution to this?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu please?

Comment: 20.04, sorry, i forgot to mention that.